# Why does file not exists even it exists?

Tags: laravel

In a Laravel application, I upload first the files in a temporary folder:

```
    public function upload(Request $request, $uploadId)
    {
        $file = $request->file('file');

        Storage::put('temporaryFiles/'.$file->getClientOriginalName(), $file->getContent());

        TemporaryFile::create([
            'uuid' => Uuid::uuid4(),
            'upload_id' => $uploadId,
            'path' => 'temporaryFiles/'.$file->getClientOriginalName(),
            'name' => str_replace('.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension(), '', $file->getClientOriginalName()),
            'file_name' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
            'extension' => $file->getClientOriginalExtension()
        ]);

        return TemporaryFile::where('upload_id', $uploadId)->get();
    }
```

After, when I store the model "order", I will move the file from the temporary folder as attachment to the order model. Therefore, I use Spatie Media Library.

```
    public function move(Request $request, Order $order)
    {
        foreach ($request->temporary_files as $file)
        {
            var_dump(file_exists(storage_path('temporaryFiles/'.$file['path'])));
            $media = $order->addMediaFromDisk(storage_path('temporaryFiles/'.$file['path']), 'public')->toMediaCollection();

            $media->update([
                'name' => $file['name'],
                'file_name' => $file['file_name']
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I always receive the following error:

```
bool(true)
{
    "message": "File `/path/from/application/api/storage/app/temporaryFiles/Print-49.pdf` does not exist",
    "exception": "Spatie\\MediaLibrary\\MediaCollections\\Exceptions\\FileDoesNotExist",
```

As we can see, the file exists (see the var_dump).

[image]

But Spatie returns always an error.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Does the file actually exist though? You say "As we can see, the file exists." but where's the proof its in the folder it's attempting to be found in?

Comment: I'm checkin git with `var_dump(file_exists(storage_path('temporaryFiles/'.$file['path'])));`
This returns true

Comment: Just a thought, but in your code you have `addMediaFromDisk(storage_path('temporaryFiles/'.$file['path']), 'public')`, but you haven't added the `public` parameter in any other uses of the `storage_path` method, so it is possible that adding `public` is the problem here? I would assume that the public would probably be looking at storage/app/public/temporaryFiles but I'm not 100%

Comment: @AndyHolmes I tried with different configurations, but no success

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I have two ideas:

1. In your file lookups, you are not adding the **'app'** directory, it should be: `file_exists(storage_path('app/temporaryFiles/'.$file['path']))`.

If this is not the problem.

2. I see, in the `upload` function, that when saving the object `TemporalyFile` in the database, the path attribute starts with `temporaryFiles/`.  And when you do the search, you precede `$file['path']` by `temporaryFiles/`. It should be: 
   `var_dump(file_exists(storage_path($file['path'])))`